# Calling client side human service from another client side human service

Tags: service, ibm-bpm

I have created two client side human services.
Now i want to call one client side human service from the second client side human service.
Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Generally moving between CSHS is handled by simply putting both CSHS in a wrapper service.  Basically service 1 can either set a variable or use multiple end points to indicate where to go next. At least one of these options is to go to CSHS 2.  We expose the wrapper service to the end user, and when they run it, they will wind up running CSHS 1, which is the first sub-service in the wrapper service.  Then some interaction with the presented Coach has them go to CSHS 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire second CSHS with the help of URL.you can expose service to user and put it in scrip to call it with window.open().